# Triggering subscribe event for children properties in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am having some trouble triggering a subscribe event in Knockout. I have an array of Schemas, each holding a number of Days. I want to trigger my subscribe event when the timestamps of a Day changes and not only when the array of Schemas changes.

This is my code so far. The subscribe event at the bottom triggers when a Schema is added or removed from the Schemas array. But not when any children properties changes.

```
{"schemas":[
    {"days":[
        {"from":"12:00","to":"17:00"},
        {"from":"06:30","to":"17:00"},
        {"from":"06:30","to":"17:00"},
        ...
    ]},
    {"days":[
        {"from":"06:30","to":"17:00"},
        {"from":"06:30","to":"17:00"},
        {"from":"06:30","to":"17:00"},
        ...
    ]}
]} 

var Schema = function(data, parent, index) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
};

var SchemaViewModelMapping = new (function() {
    var self = this;

    self.index = 0;
    self.schemas = {
        create: function(options) {
            self.index++;
            return new Schema(options.data, options.parent, self.index);
        }
    };
    self.index = 0;
})();


var SchemaViewModel = function() {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, SchemaViewModelMapping, self);

    self.schemas.subscribe(function(value) {
        **Let me do something when a DAY changes here!!!**
    });
}

var ViewModel = new SchemaViewModel;
ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

Comment: The `schemas` observable has no knowledge of the internals of the contents of the array - only the items in the array itself.  To do what you're suggesting, you'll need to make every property of each of the items in the array an `observable` or `observableArray` and subscribe to those to see any changes

Comment: Thanks.. That makes sense. I was able to solve it.

Comment: Please add it as an answer, and mark it as valid answer to help other people.

Comment: Sure.. @JamesThorpe Feel free to add it and I will accept it as valid. If not, I'll add my self later.

Comment: @Stromgren May be better if you add it, as you can include the actual code you've written to bind to your child properties etc.  I was only making a suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @JamesThorpe 's suggestion i updated my code as follows:
I've added a new Day object from where add my subscribtions, which i instantiate from the Schema.

```
{"schemas":[
    {"days":[
        {"from":"12:00","to":"17:00"},
        {"from":"06:30","to":"17:00"},
        {"from":"06:30","to":"17:00"},
        ...
    ]},
    {"days":[
        {"from":"06:30","to":"17:00"},
        {"from":"06:30","to":"17:00"},
        {"from":"06:30","to":"17:00"},
        ...
    ]}
]} 

var Day = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.from = ko.observable(data.from);
    self.to = ko.observable(data.to);
    self.from.subscribe(function() {
        **Doing my subscribe magic...**
    });
    self.to.subscribe(function() {
        **Doing my subscribe magic...**
    });
};

var Schema = function(data, parent, index) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
    self.days = ko.observableArray();
    data.days.forEach(function(day) {
      self.days.push(new Day(day));
    });
};

var SchemaViewModelMapping = new (function() {
    var self = this;

    self.index = 0;
    self.schemas = {
        create: function(options) {
            self.index++;
            return new Schema(options.data, options.parent, self.index);
        }
    };
    self.index = 0;
})();


var SchemaViewModel = function() {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, SchemaViewModelMapping, self);

    self.schemas.subscribe(function(value) {
        **Let me do something when a DAY changes here!!!**
    });
}

var ViewModel = new SchemaViewModel;
ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```